# Asterisk ami for python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, asterisk, amazon-ami

I am trying to use [obelus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/obelus/) with twisted adapter (for python 3.X), but don't understand how make calls from CallManager.
Is there anyone who uses this module or use another library in python3 for asterisk ami?

p.s. pyst, asterisk and other dont work (even could not install)

Answer (score 4):

install ajam for asterisk and use panoramisk: [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/panoramisk/), [git-hub](https://github.com/gawel/panoramisk)

Comment: panoramisk is definitely a much better solution than the older python-ami.  If you're using freepbx the manager server is already built in (these days), so you can skip the install of ajam, just `pip install panoramisk` and look at the examples on github for how it works.

Answer (score 4):

I use this lib: https://github.com/ettoreleandrotognoli/python-ami

And to start a call I use the Originate action https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

Comment: The other solution is much better.  They examples provided with this solution use a sleep timer instead of proper async and don't properly trap errors.